# How would the producer consumer problem be solve if there was 1 producer and many consumers Buffer size of 1

Tags: c, multithreading, synchronization, pthreads, producer-consumer

How would the producer consumer problem be solved if there was 1 producer which provides a filename and two consumers which consume the filename.

*The twist is that the buffer where the filename is added to is of size 1 meaning we can't have 2 copies one for each consumer to consume.*

Both consumers have different logic to run for the same file.

I haven't included the exit condition logic but it will terminate threads when the filename equals EXIT.

**Data is shared between producer/consumers with a pointer.**

*Shared Data:*

```
    char* filenameBuffer;
    pthread_mutex_t filenameMutex;
    pthread_cond_t canProduceFilename;
    pthread_cond_t canConsumeFilename;
```

Currently I had the producer doing something like this.

*Parent/Producer thread - Will loop till I want to exit.*

```
while(!exit)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(filenameMutex);

    //Check if the string is empty.
    if(filenameBuffer != '\0')
    {
        p_thread_cond_wait(canProduceFilename, filenameMutex);
    }

    scanf("%s", filenameBuffer);

    pthread_cond_signal(canConsumeFilename);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(filenameMutex);
}
```

*Children/Consumer threads - Which we have 2 of.*

```
while (!exit)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(filenameMutex);

    //Loop until a string is produced.
    while (filenameBuffer == '\0')
    {
       p_thread_cond_wait(canConsumeFilename, filenameMutex);
    }

    //Do something with filename, not relevant for solution.

    pthread_mutex_unlock(filenameMutex);
}
```

So how would I be able to consume the filename inside the consumers without controlling the order each consumer thread. I don't want to force the order of which consumer can run first as that ruins the point of multithreading.

I'll stick around if there is any clarification or more information required.

Any discussion or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards.

Comment: You will encounter serious problems when attempting to read one file simultaneously from two threads.

Comment: The reading happens inside the filename mutex hence only one consumer can read the file at a time.

Comment: I see. The consumers simply consume a string which is a filename. The fact that the string is a filename is irrelevant to the question since processing the filename is not part of the question.

Comment: Do you want both threads to process both files, or do you want each thread to essentially randomly process files from the filename list?

Comment: If you want both threads to process all filenames then implement a counter within the mutex to ensure each filename is read twice before the next filename can be read.

Comment: This code doesn't force the consumer thread order. Whichever thread happens to run first will discover the buffer non-empty and process it.

Answer (score 0):

I have concocted an example of how this works using the Ada programming language. Since the processing of file names is not important to this problem I have created two consumers that process whatever string they receive until the string equals "Exit".

This example creates a protected object containing a single element buffer and a counter. It also implements two entries, write and read. The write entry only executes when the counter equals 0. The read entry only executes when the counter is greater than 0.

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded; use Ada.Strings.Unbounded;

procedure Main is
   type Count_Type is range 0..2;
   protected buffer is
      entry write(S : in Unbounded_String);
      entry read(S : out Unbounded_String);
   private
      Counter : Count_Type := 0;
      Element : Unbounded_String;
   end Buffer;
   
   protected body buffer is
      entry write (S : in Unbounded_String) when Counter = 0 is
      begin
         Element := S;
         Counter := 2;
      end write;
      
      entry read (S : out Unbounded_String) when Counter > 0 is
      begin
         S := Element;
         Counter := Counter - 1;
      end read;
   end buffer;
   
   task producer;
   
   task body producer is
      Msg : Unbounded_String := To_Unbounded_String("Message");
   begin
      for I in 0..9 loop
         Msg := Msg & Integer'Image(I);
         Buffer.write(Msg);
      end loop;
      Msg := To_Unbounded_String("Exit");
      Buffer.Write(Msg);
   end producer;
   
   task consumer_1;
   
   task body consumer_1 is
      Msg : Unbounded_String;
   begin
      loop
         Buffer.Read(Msg);
         exit when To_String(Msg) = "Exit";
         Put_Line("Con1 -> " & To_String(Msg));
      end loop;
   end consumer_1;
   
   task consumer_2;
   
   task body consumer_2 is
      Msg : Unbounded_String;
   begin
      loop
         Buffer.Read(Msg);
         exit when To_String(Msg) = "Exit";
         Put_Line("Con2 -> " & To_String(Msg));
      end loop;
   end consumer_2;
begin
   null;
end Main;
```

The output of the program is:

```ada
Con1 -> Message 0
Con2 -> Message 0
Con1 -> Message 0 1
Con2 -> Message 0 1
Con1 -> Message 0 1 2
Con2 -> Message 0 1 2
Con2 -> Message 0 1 2 3
Con2 -> Message 0 1 2 3 4
Con1 -> Message 0 1 2 3
Con2 -> Message 0 1 2 3 4
Con1 -> Message 0 1 2 3 4 5
Con2 -> Message 0 1 2 3 4 5
Con1 -> Message 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
Con2 -> Message 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
Con1 -> Message 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Con2 -> Message 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Con1 -> Message 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
Con2 -> Message 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
Con1 -> Message 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
Con2 -> Message 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```